# Are the progressions VII - i or VII VI V part of tonal harmony?

Tags: harmony

These chord progressions are not in my tonal Harmony book. Is there a reason that anyone can think of why they would not be in there? They are very common chord progressions. I am interested to know how the VII actually functions in these chord progressions from a functional harmony perspective.

Comment: Put a "i" at the beginning of the second example and you've got the [Andalusian cadence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andalusian_cadence). See https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/98344/what-is-so-special-about-am-g-f-e-chord-progression/98347#98347

Comment: I was aware of the name of the cadence but how do those chords function in the progression?

Comment: Is i-VII-III in your tonal harmony book? I'd think the VII chord there and in VII-VI-V has a similar function in both.

Comment: Yes Dekkadeci. It is. It says the VII is applied dominant of the mediant (III) in the minor mode. This makes sense. However, I dont see how that relates to VII moving to VI or VII moving to i. Could you please explain what you mean.

Comment: You got to get a different book! Also, you've probably heard this before, but it's true, let _actual scores_ be your first textbook. The likely reason those progressions aren't in the book is roots by step are often described only with `IV V` or `V vi` especially as ascending steps to keep the textbook simple.